# Passing ARRAY of STRUCTs into user-defined function for standard BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

How would I got about passing an ARRAY of STRUCTS into my user-defined function (using standard SQL)?

Firstly, a bit of context:

**Table schema:**

```
id STRING
customer STRING
request STRUCT<
  headers STRING
  body STRING
  url STRING
>
response STRUCT<
  size INT64
  body STRING
>
outgoing ARRAY<
  STRUCT<
    request STRUCT<
      url STRING,
      body STRING,
      headers STRING
    >,
    response STRUCT<
      size INT64,
      body STRING
    >
  >
>
```

**User-defined function:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extractDetailed(
  customer STRING,
  request STRUCT<
    headers STRING,
    body STRING
  >,
  outgoing ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      request STRUCT<url STRING>,
      response STRUCT<body STRING>
    >
  >
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """

""";

SELECT extractDetailed(customer, STRUCT(request.headers, request.body), outgoing)
FROM request_logs
```

As for my problem: I can't seem to figure out how to select part of the `outgoing` ARRAY, and pass it to the user-defined function as an array.

Effectively, I'm trying to simulate the following user-defined function call:

```
extractDetailed(
  "customer id",
  { "headers": "", "body": "" },
  [
    {
      "request": { "url": "" },
      "response": { "body": "" }
    },
    {
      "request": { "url": "" },
      "response": { "body": "" }
    }
  ]
);
```

I have recently stumbled across [some documentation that might help](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#expression-subqueries) unlock it, I just can't seem to figure out how to make it fit. I'm really struggling with this, and would appreciate any help in resolving it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below. It parses needed peaces from your array and puts them back into new array before passing to function so it matches sugnature

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extractDetailed(
customer STRING,
request STRUCT<headers STRING, body STRING>,
outgoing ARRAY<STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING>, response STRUCT<body STRING>>>
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """

""";

SELECT 
  extractDetailed(
    customer, 
    STRUCT(request.headers, request.body), 
    ARRAY(
      SELECT STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING>,response STRUCT<body STRING>>
          (STRUCT(request.url), STRUCT(response.body)) 
      FROM UNNEST(outgoing)
    )
  ) AS details
FROM request_logs
```

To further "optimize" above query and make it more portable, you can wrap extracting parts from original array to new array into separate SQL UDF

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extractParts (
  outgoing ARRAY<STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING, body STRING, headers STRING>,
                        response STRUCT<size INT64, body STRING>>>
)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING>, response STRUCT<body STRING>>>
AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING>,response STRUCT<body STRING>>
          (struct(request.url), struct(response.body)) 
      FROM UNNEST(outgoing)
    )
));

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION extractDetailed(
  customer STRING,
  request STRUCT<headers STRING, body STRING>,
  outgoing ARRAY<STRUCT<request STRUCT<url STRING>, response STRUCT<body STRING>>>
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return outgoing.length;
""";

SELECT 
  extractDetailed(
    customer, 
    STRUCT(request.headers, request.body),
    extractParts(outgoing)
  ) as details
FROM request_logs
```

Comment: So, from a performance point of view, is there any difference between the two? My first thought around having two UDF's is that it would cause a slight slowdown. But I'm guessing it might be a tradeoff between portability and performance.

Comment: from my experience SQL UDF is not adding to slowness. JS UDF could. So, i feel two above should perform the same